# My Standard Neural Network Cost is Going Up

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have been trying to create a simple standard neural network from scratch but I can't seem to get it to work normally. Sometimes the cost skyrockets, other times the cost doesn't even change. I'm not sure what the problem is but it would be really helpful if someone could help me.

I have all of the information on Github. If any more information is needed kindly reply and I will provide it.

https://github.com/enriquedellxps/Neural-Network

Function for generating batches:

```py
def batcher(data, batch_size):
    # get the number of batches
    num_batches_norem = data.shape[1] // batch_size
    if data.shape[1] % batch_size == 0:
        remainder_quantity = 0
    else:
        remainder_size = data.shape[1] % batch_size
        remainder_quantity = 1
    num_batches = num_batches_norem + remainder_quantity

    changer = 0
    for mb in range(num_batches_norem):
        current_batch = data[:, changer:changer + batch_size]
        changer += batch_size

        yield current_batch

    for last_mb in range(remainder_quantity):
        last_batch = data[:, changer:changer + remainder_size]

        yield last_batch
```

Function for g(z):

```py
def activationer(a, z):
    # ACTIVATION FUNCTIONS
    # Sigmoid Activation Function
    def sigmoid(z):
        g = scipy.special.expit(z)
        return g

    # Tanh (Hyperbolic Tangent Function) Activation Function
    def tanh(z):
        g = (np.exp(z) - np.exp(-1 * z)) / ((np.exp(z) + np.exp(-1 * z)))
        return g

    # ReLU (Rectified Linear Unit) Activation Function
    def ReLU(z):
        g = np.maximum(0, z)
        return g

    # Leaky ReLU (Leaky Rectified Linear Unit) Activation Function
    def Leaky_ReLU(z):
        g = np.maximum(0.01 * z, z)
        return g

    def softmax(z):
        z_exp = np.exp(z)
        g = z_exp / np.sum(z_exp, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        return g

    if a == "sigmoid":
        res = sigmoid(z)
    elif a == "tanh":
        res = tanh(z)
    elif a == "relu":
        res = ReLU(z)
    elif a == "leaky relu":
        res = Leaky_ReLU(z)
    elif a == "softmax":
        res = softmax(z)

    return res
```

NN Class:

```py
class DeepNeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, n_x, n_h, n_y, nl, activations, alpha):
        assert nl == len(activations), f"L: {nl}, Number of Activations: {len(activations)}"

        # Assign inputs to the self object
        self.n_x = n_x
        self.n_h = n_h
        self.n_y = n_y
        self.nl = nl
        self.activations = activations
        self.alpha = alpha

    # Initialize Parameters
    def initialize_parameters(self):
        n_x = self.n_x
        n_h = self.n_h
        n_y = self.n_y
        activations = self.activations

        parameters = []
        for l in range(self.nl):
            np.random.seed(8)
            if l == 0:
                if activations[l] == "relu" or "leaky relu":
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) * np.sqrt(2 / n_x), np.zeros((n_h, 1))]) # aka W1, b1 | Xavier
                else:
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) * np.sqrt(1 / n_x), np.zeros((n_h, 1))]) # aka W1, b1 | He
            elif l == self.nl - 1:
                if activations[l] == "relu" or "leaky relu":
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_y, n_h) * np.sqrt(2 / n_h), np.zeros((n_y, 1))]) # aka WL, bL | Xavier
                else:
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_y, n_h) * np.sqrt(1 / n_h), np.zeros((n_y, 1))]) # aka WL, bL | He
            else:
                if activations[l] == "relu" or "leaky relu":
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_h, n_h) * np.sqrt(2 / n_h), np.zeros((n_h, 1))]) # hidden params | Xavier
                else:
                    parameters.append([np.random.randn(n_h, n_h) * np.sqrt(1 / n_h), np.zeros((n_h, 1))]) # hidden params | He

        return parameters

    # Forward Propagation
    def forward_propagation(self, parameters, input_data):
        batch_size = input_data.shape[1] # Get the amount of examples in the batch
        caches = []
        self.caches = caches

        current_activation = input_data # Set first activation - A0 - as the input
        caches.append(current_activation)
        for l in range(self.nl):
            W, b = parameters[l][0], parameters[l][1] # Get weights and biases for current layer

            Z = W @ current_activation + b # Compute the linear activation
            current_activation = activationer(self.activations[l], Z) # Compute the full activation
            caches.append(current_activation)

        return current_activation

    # Compute Cost
    def compute_cost(self, yhat, y):
        batch_size = y.shape[1] # Get the amount of examples in the batch
        cost = (1 / batch_size) * np.sum(-1 * (y * np.log(yhat) + ((1 - y) * (np.log(1 - yhat))))) # Compute the cross-entropy cost
        cost = np.squeeze(cost) # Turn [[17]] to 17

        return cost

    # Backward Propagation
    def backward_propagation(self, parameters, y):
        caches = self.caches
        batch_size = y.shape[1]
        grads = []


        for l in reversed(range(1, self.nl + 1)):
            if l == self.nl:
                dZ = caches[l] - y
                dW = (1 / batch_size) * dZ @ caches[l - 1].T
                db = (1 / batch_size) * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)

                grads.append([dW, db])
            else:
                dA = parameters[l][0].T @ dZ
                dZ = dA * np.multiply(caches[l], (1 - caches[l]))
                dW = (1 / batch_size) * dZ @ caches[l - 1].T
                db = (1 / batch_size) * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)

                grads.append([dW, db])

        return grads

    # Update Parameters
    def update_parameters(self, parameters, gradients):
        for l in range(self.nl):
            parameters[l][0] = parameters[l][0] - self.alpha * gradients[self.nl - l - 1][0]
            parameters[l][1] = parameters[l][1] - self.alpha * gradients[self.nl - l - 1][1]
        return parameters
```

Running it:

```py
dnn = DeepNeuralNetwork(12288, 20, 1, 4, ["relu", "relu", "relu", "sigmoid"], 0.001)
params = dnn.initialize_parameters()
epochs = 100

for e in range(epochs):
    for i, j in zip(train_x_batched, train_y_batched):
        yhat = dnn.forward_propagation(params, i)
        cost = dnn.compute_cost(yhat, j)
        grads = dnn.backward_propagation(params, j)
        params = update_parameters(params, grads)

        print(cost) # This usually starts going down then skyrockets. Even if I lower the learning rate to 0.00001
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @EnriqueReid, could you post your code directly in the question with triple backtick?

Comment: Please read [mre] and [ask]. The question has to be self-contained, and nobody is going to bother reading all code in a large project. If you can’t distill down your problem, then Stack Overflow might not be the right place to ask.

Comment: @EnriqueReid It's fine, at least we will be able to pinpoint where you are doing the gradient-descent step and double check if everything is wired up properly there. Worst case someone will edit the non-important part out.

Comment: It's not a large project at all. Just a small classifier of mine but thanks for your advice :). @YacineMahdid thanks for your help

Comment: Personally I think it would be easier to use the Github because the datasets and functions are all already there.